# how access to the properties of a <form> in Angular.js using a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the html I write

```
{{form.$error}}
```

The result is:

```
{"required":[{}]}
```

I need access to the before result, but inside of directive.

for example '

```
console.log(x) => "required"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2fam9yt1/

Answer (score 0):

I saw your fiddle and I'm getting what you're trying to do. You're trying to access $error inside directive 'validate', let me know if I'm wrong.

For that you just access it from DOM's scope like this

```
scope.form.$error
```

inside your link function.

You can try this,

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       console.log(scope.form.$error);
        if (!ngModel){
          return;          
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your fiddle,what I am understanding,you are trying to create your own `custom validators` like `required`.

You can do it in this way.

```
app.directive('validate', function($timeout) {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log(ctrl, 'ctrl');
      ctrl.$validators.validate = function(modalValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modalValue)) {
          return false; // logic for false case
        } else {
          //return true; //login for true case
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

In the above script `modalValue` will give access to update value before

[`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/W7jtx14UZaMXYthl6AY7?p=preview)

For more [`read here`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)